# Programação em C - Matrizes Bidimensional

Tags: c, array, matriz

**Erro na Impressão da matriz.Não consegue gerar as linhas da matriz.

Observação, sem utilizar outra biblioteca**

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nlinhas,mcolunas;
    int matriz[nlinhas][mcolunas];
    int n,m;//n linhas, m colunas

    //inserir o número de linhas e colunas

    printf("Insira os número de linhas\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&nlinhas);
    printf("Insira o número de colunas\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&mcolunas);

    printf("\nDigite as coordenadas da matriz\n\n");

    for (n=0;n < nlinhas; n++)
        for (m=0;m < mcolunas; m++)
        {
            printf("coordenadas [%d][%d]: \n", n, m);
            scanf("%d",&matriz[n][m]);
        }   
    for (n=0; n<nlinhas; n++)
    {
        for (m = 0; m<mcolunas; m++)
            printf("%2d",matriz[n][m]);
        printf("\n"); 
        //salto de linhas matricial
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está em você declarar `nlinhas[]` enquanto você provavelmente não queria um vetor, e você precisa declarar a variável `matriz[nlinhas][mcolunas]` depois que você já possui os valores `nlinhas` e `mcolunas`.

```
int nlinhas,mcolunas;
printf("Insira os número de linhas\n\n");
scanf("%d",&nlinhas);
printf("Insira o número de colunas\n\n");
scanf("%d",&mcolunas);
int matriz[nlinhas][mcolunas];
int n,m;//n linhas, m colunas
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está declarando uma matriz de tamanho nxm sem antes ter n ou m, qual o tamanho que você espera que essa matriz tenha?

Sem utilizar ponteiros apontando para ponteiros e alocação dinâmica, a maneira mais fácil que eu posso te sugerir para resolver esse problema seria declarar a matriz apenas depois de obter as entradas do usuário.

```
int main()
{
    int nlinhas, mcolunas;

    //inserir o número de linhas e colunas

    printf("Insira os número de linhas\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&nlinhas);
    printf("Insira o número de colunas\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&mcolunas);

    //--------------------------------------------//

    int matriz[nlinhas][mcolunas];
    int n, m; //n linhas, m colunas

    printf("\nDigite as coordenadas da matriz\n\n");

    for (n=0;n < nlinhas; n++)
        for (m=0;m < mcolunas; m++)
        {
            printf("coordenadas [%d][%d]: \n", n, m);
            scanf("%d",&matriz[n][m]);
        }   
    for (n=0; n<nlinhas; n++)
    {
        for (m = 0; m<mcolunas; m++)
            printf("%2d",matriz[n][m]);
        printf("\n"); 
        //salto de linhas matricial
    }
}
```